# In entity framework core identity, using "UpdateSecurityStampAsync" method than also logged in user didn't kick out to login page. why?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular6, identity

When user role is changed or rest password then security stamp is an update of that user by using "UpdateSecurityStampAsync" method then also user didn't kick out to log in.

Note:
-We are using the Entity framework core, Identity, .net core, Jwt Configurations and angular in frontend.
-We are using Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer") on controller.

Answer (score 1):

It won't. The security stamp has to be revalidated first before that will happen, which by default happens every 30 minutes. You can lower this interval if you like. However, the lower the interval, the more your database will be queried. You can lower it all the way to zero, to have it always immediately revalidated, but that will then require a database query with every request.

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => {
    o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```